# The "CreateSilverlightAppManifest" task was not given a value for the required parameter "SilverlightRuntimeVersion"

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

While trying to compile a Silverlight project for Windows Phone using Visual Studio 2010 I received this (attached) odd error:

> The "CreateSilverlightAppManifest" task was not given a value for the
>   required parameter "SilverlightRuntimeVersion"

If I double click it nothing happens, no file is open. Google is not my friend on this one :) Did anyone also encountered this error and found a solution?

I mention that:

- I have some experience in C#/XAML/WPF/VS2010, but no Silverlight/Windows Phone specific knowledge;
- I have installed Silverlight 4 SDK and Windows Phone Toolkit.

[image]

Comment: Searching for your error got me here: http://ngenerics.googlecode.com/svn-history/r318/trunk/Source/Dependencies/SilverlightForPhoneV4.0/Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets perhaps it can help you? Or perhaps try to reinstall the windows phone sdk.

Comment: The SDK was freshly installed seconds before compiling the project, so I don't think this would be the problem. But who knows, maybe worth a try. I will come back after re-installing it. I've also found that on Google, but I need more time to investigate that code in order to find if there's something there that can help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution for this problem, so I have taken advantage of this "opportunity" to re-install my entire OS and development tools :) The problem didn't occur after this couple-of-hours process.